# Discrete and visible div over img/video

Tags: html, css, visibility, transparency

I have an video tag with an div displayed on top. The div is pretty nice looking and visible for the most part, only dark images are a bit problematic.

For the sake of testing I searched out 3 pictures and overlay them with my div.

### The question is, how would someone create this overlay layout, so it is discreetly and clearly visible at the same time?

The result is as follows:

[image: Visibility good!] **Visibility good!**

[image: Visibility bad] **Visibility bad**

[image: Visibility bad] **Visibility okay, background visibility bad**

---

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tag{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
    padding: 5px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;

    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/20140824_0304_171.jpg"></img>
    <div class="tag">Hello Tag</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://alifebeyondrubies.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/walls01.jpg"></img>
    <div class="tag">Hello Tag</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://photos.epicurious.com/2015/01/12/54b4006b2413537c0d45738f_51143820_spaghetti-mussels-white-beans_6x4.jpg"></img>
    <div class="tag">Hello Tag</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vince was a huge help, ty for this great resource.

Solution I ended up doing:

https://jsfiddle.net/p89buajq/

I am still fiddling with the color but the concept is nice, ty everyone.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Though you might wanna mark the most helpful answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to provide text-shadow with blur as shown in the image below, so this helps in getting a form of translucent background around the text.

Please try:- [CSS3 Text Shadow Generator](http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/)

text-shadow: 3px 0px 19px rgba(226, 150, 150, 1);

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some options.

I'll skip the options that aren't applicable for your problem:

- apply text directly to image
- overlay entire image

Here are the useful ones:

## 1. Text in a box

This is the option you chose, you could tweak the opacity a bit so it's more readable on 'noisy' images.

**Idea**

[image: Textbox overlay]

## 2. Blur the part behind the text

[image: Blurred background]

## 3. Floor fade

A slight fading effect behind the text. **Hint:** Use a text shadow!

[image: Floor fade]

## 4. Scrim

This is an interesting one. It's a kind of gradiated box behind the text. It should not be noticeable but the text should be easier to read.

The floor fade's **hint** applies here as well.

[image: Scrim]

Reference: https://medium.com/@erikdkennedy/7-rules-for-creating-gorgeous-ui-part-2-430de537ba96